# How to prevent that java.exe is installed in Windows' system32?

Tags: windows, installation, jvm, java

Is there a way to prevent that the Java installation routine (e.g. *jdk-7u1-windows-i586.exe*) copies **java.exe** into `C:\Windows\system32` directory?

I have to install my software on a client's laptop and I don't want to break other Java applications which are already installed on the machine. In other words I want to install a **private JRE** which is only used by my software.

By now, I copied an already installed JRE from my computer to the client's machine.

Comment: I thought Java installer always installs itself into a standalone directory.  No?  That and I thought that Java could be installed in an xcopy fashion by just copying the installation directory to another machine.

Comment: @selbie: it *can* be installed this way, but that's not what the installer does by default: it *does* install the JRE to its own directory but *also* copies the `java.exe` to the `system32` directory.

Comment: @selbie: the installer additionally creates some registry keys. I did not find a simple **zip archive** for Windows which could be used instead of the installer.

Comment: You can create a setup installer that bundles private JRE (a copy of whole JRE folder rather than a setup.exe) into your app's directory instead default Java installation path and asks java launcher to your Java app to refer to this private JRE. Launch4J supports this launch setup. It will not interfere with user's installed JRE if there is.

Comment: You can really wonder why messing with the System32 folder when there is a JAVA_HOME env var specifically made to indicate where Java is. Amazing

Answer (score 8):

I discovered yesterday that there is a **problem with Java versions on Windows**, as you know keeping java up to date these days is critical, especially the JRE used by Internet explorer located in the Windows system32 or syswow64 folder.

You can perform a search for java in your C: drive and look at the various executable files it finds to determine if the situation applies on a specific system.

After doing some research I find that when the **Java updater** runs, it only updates the files installed in the JAVA home , usually located on the program files, but it **does NOT update the files located in the windows system folder**.    As a result and since the system folder is in the default system PATH , the usage of Internet Explorer continues to use an old version of the JAVA files ( java.exe , javaw.exe , javaws.exe )

The **solution** is to **uninstall java using the control panel** uninstall programs feature, **download most recent version and install again**.

Cheers!
Fernando

Comment: I don't think this is the case. The Windows System32 directory only holds java.exe and other java launchers. The actual VM (jvm.dll) and supporting libraries/classes are within the JDK/JRE directory that gets updated by Java updater.

Answer (score 6):

I recently upgraded to java 8 and discovered this problem as the java version under system32 was still java 7.  It stops you even running version as it complains about the registry keys

```
U:\>java -version
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Doing the following pointed me to the culprit:

```
U:\>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe
```

I 'solved' this problem by just deleting the java under system32!  I'm unsure of what consequences this will have.

Comment: You probably avoided more problems than created by doing so ! It is way better to have a program crash telling you it cannot find java rather than one that runs with a deprecated version of java and you're not even aware of it.

Comment: What other should we delete (or rather move to a temporary folder)?  At least java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe, JavaScriptCollectionAgent.dll right?  The dll appears to be in use so it cannot be moved.  Are there others?

Comment: @snaran no idea sorry, this did the job for me at the time

Comment: Its been 3 years.  Did you discover any problems?

Comment: @Lucas I didn't keep using java all that time but I don't  recall any problems

Answer (score 4):

You can just provide the JRE you want to use on your software and:

- Set the `JAVA_HOME` variable before you run your application
- Point to the correct java.exe file (e.g. `..\jre1.5.0_22\bin\java <your_java_main>`)

This can be done in a *.bat file for example.

After running the *.bat file you created, all other java version will be ignored and it won't matter which versions are, or will be, installed on that pc.

Comment: This would only ensure that *my application* uses the correct JRE. Other applications which are already installed on the machine might break if they do not set the JAVA_HOME and rely on using the default JRE which is usually in _system32_. But if I install a new JRE (possibly a beta version) the **java.exe** is copied into system32 and as a consequence other Java applications might use a beta JRE. That's the problem.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is only needed when using JDK, not JRE. JRE automatically uses System property `java.home` to get the Java default path from Windows registry

Comment: Binding changes done with `SET` only last for the duration of a cmd session, so it won't affect other applications. You could ensure that the user doesn't try to launch any other applications from the same cmd session by calling `exit` at the end of your batch file.

Comment: You can use "setx" to persist the changes to the environment variables.  A few items to note: it does not change the environment in the current session as "set" does.  Also on my system, I can not change the entire path using it without admin privileges - so system32 always comes first in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I found the newest JDK still doesn't write correct code against registry. 
The issue is if a computer doesn't have JRE, JDK doesn't register JRE in registry correctly.

For those install JDK 1.7u72 Just add Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment as the error message indicate. And add a string entry of CurrentVersion with value 1.7.
And then add Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7 and put a JavaHome string entry with value "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7". And JRE will function correctly. 
Blame Oracle, if you use Registry, then write correct code, otherwise don't use the Registry!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is go to Control Panel -> Programs Uninstall a program. Uninstall the old java updates and keep the newest java update and java development kit update.  Your newest java update and java development kit update should have the same number.

Comment: Need 1.6 and 1.8

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 10 Solution**

1. Check Java Version in Console (CMD) with  `java -version`
2. Check in Console (CMD) with  `where java`, which Java Path's are enlisted.

- If it you shows you "C:\Windows\System32" in its output, you will have a problem to get to your %JAVA_HOME%, where your wanted Java version resides.
- Meaning, you need to get rid of "java.exe" in "C:\Windows\System32".

3. Just uninstall the JRE in the Software ("Programs and Features")
   Hint: Keep in mind, do **NOT** the JDK, here in my case "Java SE Development Kit 8 Update (64-bit)"), but the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

One way I would try would be to create a write-only empty file with the name java.exe into the System32 folder.

Comment: This would not be an option. What if a "real" java.exe is already in system32.