# How come java is found in this case?

Tags: windows, windows-7, 64-bit, java

I am confused here:
If I run `java` from `cmd` then the command runs succesfully.
But I have neither set `JAVA_HOME` nor `%JRE_HOME%` nor added java/jre installation directory in my `PATH`.
So when I do

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

No JAVA_HOME is displayed (expected since I have not set it)

If I do:

echo %JRE_HOME%`

No JRE_HOME is displayed (expected since I have not set it)

and when I do

```
echo %PATH%
```

no directory in the PATH points to a java installation. Expected since I have not modified PATH to add java.

PATH is:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;  
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;  
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;   
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;  
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit-32;  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
```

So why don't I get `Bad Command` on running java?
[image]

Comment: That snapshot seems like white ants crawling over black mat. No one can see a single letter there. So its no point in posting it. Rather write the path from where you are using that command.

Comment: The path where I run java is: `C:\Users`

Comment: What does echo %PATH% return to you? It doesn't appear on your snapshot.

Comment: @DanielPereira:Can you see the snapshot?I see that RohitJain is right. I will put these in the OP.

Comment: It has to be in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: there is no result for echo %PATH%, can you write command SET, and look the value of Path.
Java must be there, or C:\Users directory.

Comment: are you sure you don't have some sort of simlink to java in your users directory?

Comment: @JonTaylor:I have no idea what you are asking me, so I would say no

Comment: Well in your Users directory there may be a file which acts essentially as a pointer to the real java.exe file.  This would negate the need for any path variables when working in the user directory.

Comment: Did you change the default Java install directory? Please, post the directory of your current Java version.

Comment: @RohitJain there's nothing wrong with that screenshot, you just have to view the full-size image instead of the resized version SO shows you. Cratylus, did you install something that depends on Java and therefore installed Java on its own when it didn't find an existing installation? That could put it in an unexpected directory. Less likely, you could've added Java under an environment variable with a non-standard name, or perhaps directly in the `Users` directory.

Comment: Okay, I see the OP edited, so for convenience: [original screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGzBr.png) and [updated screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6MScM.png)

Comment: @LordTorgamus:Used the `where` command as the answer by MartinElis (did not know about this) and it displayed: `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`. Is this bundled in `Windows 7` or did I install it sometime in the past and did not remember this?

Comment: @Cratylus according to Joachim Sauer, [the `System32` directory is the (or a) new default location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223511/how-to-prevent-that-java-exe-is-installed-in-windows-system32#comment10112260_8223511).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/611182) to "Is there an equivalent of 'which' on windows?", recent versions of Windows include a 'where' command.

So you could try: `where java.exe`

I can't check right now, but I have a feeling Windows had a java.exe somewhere under `C:\Windows\System32\`…

Comment: Had *NO* idea about this.Will accept this as soon as it is permitted (5 mins I think)

Comment: What is this java? It is bundled in `Windows`?

Comment: @Cratylus just out of curiosity, was it in fact under System32?

Comment: if your system has no where command. You can try "dir /s /b java.exe" at root (c:\)

Comment: @LordTorgamus:Yes.Under `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`.Have no idea why it is there.Is it part of `Windows 7`?Or did I somehow installed it in the past?

Comment: Found another answer that might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11063953/611182 :)