# Error in Eclipse: An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites",org/eclipse/ecf/core/identity/ID

Tags: eclipse, java-8

Please remove the Java JDK 8 Early Access from your system or change the system default from the JDK 8. The system default can normally be removed by using the Java Control Panel in Windows 7. However, with the JDK 8, for some reason, this default could not be changed. The only way was to uninstall. Hopefully Oracle will change this behavior soon . Can someone help me how to change the default JDK in the Java Control panel.

Comment: Could you rephrase this question and give additional details on what exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about using the Java Control Panel but I found that after installing JDK8 copies of java.exe, javaws.exe and javaw.exe are placed inside your system32 folder and override what is set on your PATH environment variable which causes the error message you describe in the title.

The solutions I tried were:

To back up these files and remove them from the system32 folder ensuring my PATH environment was set correctly to my desired JDK and then reopen Eclipse and it worked fine.

And to change my PATH enviroment variable so that the JDK was before: 
%SystemRoot%\system32;

I've written a blog post on this that I will edit in later today when I have published it but that's essentially all I did.

The first answer to this question is related to the java.exe being placed in system32: [How to prevent that java.exe is installed in Windows' system32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223511/how-to-prevent-that-java-exe-is-installed-in-windows-system32)

Edit: Here it is http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/03/why-installing-java-8-may-break-your-system/