# how to tell which java version cgywin use?

Tags: java, cygwin

i have cgywin and java 7 installed on window 7, also updated the system environment variable to point to the right java version, however when I run commands in cgywin, I m not sure which java it use, here is the commands and results:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_17

$ which java
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java

export 
declare -x JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_17"
```

why all the versions are different?

Comment: What does the PATH environment variable contain?  You may have the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223511/how-to-prevent-that-java-exe-is-installed-in-windows-system32

Comment: declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Services/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin:/cygdrive/c/maven/bin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PATH has two directories where it can find `java` one is under windows which picks a version installed (I imagine using the registry) and another is in your JDK.  There is no `javac` in your Windows directory so it finds the on in your JDK.

To keep things simple I would just have one version of Java 7 JDK installed unless you really need multiple versions.  I would change your path so it have the version of Java you want first, rather than near the end.

Comment: to clarify, you probably have a Java plugin installed default in the system which puts a java.exe in your Windows directory somewhere, which is on the system path of course, AND a JDK you also added which is also on the path but at lower priority. Remove java*.exe from the windows/system32 directory and it should pick up the ones from the jdk installation instead.