# Updating java 6 to java 7 on windows 8

Tags: java

My windows machine came with JRE6. I have installed JDK7. So now when I do

```
javac -version
```

it says 7, but when I do

```
java -version
```

it still defaults to 6.

I have set path to include JDK7, and correctly can now use javac (version 7) anywhere on the command line. However, there has never been a java_home set, so I set it to point to the JDK7 but still when I use java command it is using version 6.

Is there some default setting somewhere to remove?

Comment: Have a look for `java.exe` in `Windows\system32`.

Comment: probably you still have java6 in path

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223511/how-to-prevent-that-java-exe-is-installed-in-windows-system32 discusses the problem further.

Comment: If you no more need JRE6 which came by default, uninstall it to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set the system variable JAVA_HOME "C:\XXXX\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"