# Java jdk path setting in windows

Tags: java

I delete jdk\bin path from environment variables path in windows but when ı write "java -version" in anywhere , it still returns true results . How ?

Comment: Have you opened a new terminal? If not, you'd still have the environment variables from before you deleted it from your settings.

Comment: Yes ı opened new terminal but it returns same result

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `where` command, to check which `java` application is executed when you run `java -version`

[Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: Yes after this "where java"  , result : C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

Comment: you can look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223511/how-to-prevent-that-java-exe-is-installed-in-windows-system32 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063831/what-is-the-difference-between-system32-java-exe-and-program-files-java-jdk1 to find an answer how it got there. Probably you can simply remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just type `where java` in cmd console, and you'll get where it is. And as it shows, **I think you need check this location(C:\Windows\System32)**, when you instal java, Java exe files are copied to windows System32 folder, java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe are available there.

Comment: Yes , after "where java" , result is C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

Comment: Ok, you can delete  them or replace with other version's, then open a new terminal and check the version.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system and try again. In case, it's still pointing after restart, please check the path variable correctly. Might be some referrence still exist in either system/user path variable and thus giving the result.